# React Native Conditional Mapping Return

Tags: javascript, react-native, array.prototype.map

I have an array, `splitByDay`:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "Day": "Sunday",
    "data": "Upper",
  },
  Object {
    "Day": "Monday",
    "data": "Lower",
  },
]
```

and a function:

```
const getDay = (it) => {

          splitByDay.map((x, i) => {
            let day = x["Day"];
              if (day === it){

              return x["data"]
              } else { return "Rest" }
            
          })
      }
```

inside a `FlatList`, I pass in `it` which is the current day.

My goal is to return the corresponding piece of `data` if the day aligns. Here is the how its called:

```
 <Text style={[tailwind(`text-gray-300 font-[400px] text-[11px]`), {color: item === currentDay ? colors.purple : 'white'}]}>{getDay(item)}</Text>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you try to filter and map the data at once inside the map function. You should split that up, first filter the data and then map the data you want.

For example this code:

```
  const getDay = (it) => {
    return splitByDay.filter((x)=> x["Day"] === it).map((x) => x["Data"])[0]
  }
```